# How to export a table to excel with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, excel

I've a feeling this is more simpler than I imagine it to be...

I'm trying to create a button on a webpage that exports a table to MS excel or other spreadsheet software. Well, it's not strictly a table but a UL of list items (in place of rows) which contain divs (in place of table data cells).

Tried several things. The solutions I've used so far don't error per se, and they seem to retrieve the data I want them to retrieve. But they don't work D:

```
$('.export-to-excel').click(_.bind(function(e){
   var a = $('<a/>').appendTo('.contents');
   var table = $('mytable');
   var table_rows = $('mytable').find('li.rows');
   var data_type  = 'data:application/csv;charset=utf-8';
   a.href  = data_type + ', ' + table_rows;
   a.download = 'exported_table_' + '.xls';
   a.click();
   e.PreventDefault();
}, this));
```

And several other things. This be the shortest so far.

Comment: Do you have a server-side? I.e, PHP, MVC/ASP, Node.js or anything that could handle the web page not from the client-side, in your application?

Comment: You would parse the html to a comma separated values format and offer up a .CSV

Comment: @AlexK. Say my table looks like this :
<div class=mytable>
   <li class="row"></li>
       <div class="cells">
       <div class="cells">
      
   <li class="row"></li>
   <li class="row"></li>
   <li class="row"></li>
</div>
How would I parse into csvs and offer up a .CSV? O_o

Comment: The right tool for this job is to create a [data: URI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme), which is a virtual URI not located on any server, but can still be downloaded by the browser. Luckily, there are plugins that do that for you, which you have located. Do these plugins not suffice for some reason?

Comment: I have to work on an offline machine. So can't download said plugins. I can request one if it's *really* worth it. What plugins did you have in mind? Is there a way I can do it without the plugins (Or would that be way too much code to write?)

Answer (score 0):

You can't create a file with javascript. Well, you can read and manipulate it, but it's not crossbrowser (http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/). You need a server backend to make a file and make it downloadable.

You can use PHP that's easy to install-configure-development. It has a XLS object to play with it. I recommend this: https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/

Good luck

Comment: Sure it's impossible with pure JavaScript? I found some JavaScript/jQuery plugins on Git that seem to do the job for tables formatted with table tags. It's just my developing work at my job has to be done on an offline machine because reasons. I'd copy out the code for said plugins but they are very long. And 'twould be a lot of work only to discover they don't work for whatever reason. 

Unfortunately Gaweyne only knows how to speak JavaScript D:

Comment: Maybe the options that you are thinking uses Node.js. This creates a backend server in pure javascript, but it's a server ;). As I tell you, this is so hard in javascript. I will investigate for this and I tell you as soon as possible. I work last years with file manipulation in javascript, but is read-only, not writing.

Comment: Ah yes. I am using Node.js. I scarcely know anything about Node.js. I'm still the new guy here. :s

Comment: Yes, using node.js you have a server. I don't have knowledge of how node.js works, I can't help you with this.

Comment: This is the plugin I was thinking of: http://jordiburgos.com/post/2014/excellentexport-javascript-export-to-excel-csv.html

Comment: There's nothing "not crossbrowser" about HTML File API. It's supported by Firefox 3.0+, Chrome 13+, Internet Explorer 10+, Safari 6+, and of course all other browsers based off those. The main problem with the File API is actually that it _can't_ manipulate files.

Comment: You are the luckiest man if your clients don't need to compatibility IE<10 . I am envy of you hahaha

Comment: Solved it. No need for server-side solution. Can be done by looping through the table and exporting as a HTML string. Might post the solution when I have time but it's very long.